# How to access view controller variables from the app delegate... and vice versa?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I would like the view controller to be able to access `dog` in the app delegate.

I would like the app delegate to be able to access `mouse` in the view controller.

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    int mouse;  // <----------------
}
@end
```

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mouse = 12;  // <-------------------

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad %d", dog); // <---------------
}
```

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    int dog;  // <---------------
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

---

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillResignActive %d", mouse); // <--------------
}
```

---

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    dog = 77; // <---------------------

    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");
}
```

Comment: How do any two objects access each other's variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part 1:
In the ViewController.h:

```
-(int)mouse;  //add this before the @end
```

In the ViewController.m, add this method:

```
-(int)mouse
{
    return mouse;
}
```

To access mouse from AppDelegate, use self.viewController.mouse
For example;

```
NSLog(@"ViewController mouse: %i", self.viewController.mouse);
```

Part2:

In the AppDelegate.h:

```
-(int)dog;  //add this before the @end
```

In the AppDelegate.m, add this method:

```
-(int)dog
{
    return dog;
}
```

In the ViewController.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

To access dog from ViewController, use this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"dog from AppDelegate: %i", [appDelegate dog]);  //etc.
```

Comment: In Part 1: `self.viewController.mouse` possible to send arguments?

Answer (score 6):

In your view controller header file add mouse as a property:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSInteger mouse;  // <----------------
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger mouse;

@end
```

Synthesize the property in your view controller implementation just below the @implementation line:

```
@synthesize mouse;
```

In your app delegate add dog as a property:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSInteger dog;  // <---------------
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger dog;

@end
```

Also synthesize dog in your app delegate implementation.

Now in your app delegate, assuming you have a reference to your view controller, you can access mouse like this:

```
viewController.mouse = 13;
```

You can do the same thing with your app delegate class, which can be accessed from any view controller using (assuming the name of your app delegate class is AppDelegate):

```
((AppDelegate *)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)).dog = 13;
```

I would recommend that you use also use NSInteger instead of int.

Comment: (viewController.mouse = 13;) need "self" -> (self.viewController.mouse = 13;)

Comment: That would actually depend on whether or not viewController is a synthesized property of the app delegate.  If it was then yes this would be the preferred method of accessing it.